# Angular 6 - multiple conditions for custom directives

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I make a custom directive `[showIfUser]` that to show and hide routes based on users' roles. There are 3 roles for users as 'PRIMARY', 'SUBTITUTE', and 'USER'. A user may have multiple roles and allowed to see specific routes based on their roles. My custom directive only works for a single condition but how to check the multiple conditions in the directives? For example: this works: `<a href="/" *showIfUser="'PRIMARY'"></a>`, but this does not: `<a href="/link" *showIfUser="'PRIMARY' || 'SUBSTITUTE'"></a>`

custom.directive.ts:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[showIfUser]'
})
@AutoUnsubscribe([])
export class ShowIfLoggedInDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() showIfUser;

  roleSub = new Subscription();

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.roleSub = this.authService.roles$.subscribe((roles: string[]) => {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      if (roles.length && roles.includes(this.showIfUser)) {
        if (this.showIfUser) {
          this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
      } else {
        if (!this.showIfUser && !roles.includes('USER') && !roles.includes('PRIMARY') && !roles.includes('SUBSTITUTE')) {
          this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
          this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the doesn't work is you are using a logical or operator when saying
`"'PRIMARY' || 'SUBSTITUTE'"`so it will always return **primary** in this case as it is the first truthful value.

I would recommend changing your showIfUser variable within your directive to be and array type

```
@Input() showIfUser:string[];
```

And then in the HTML

```
<a href="/link" *showIfUser="['PRIMARY','SUBSTITUTE']"></a>
```

And finally perhaps change your check to see if the users role matches by using

```
if(roles.some(r=> this.showIfUser.includes(r)))
```